# More than one REST service with similar parameters for both request and responses

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, restful-url, wcf-rest

I would like to create more than one C# webAPI [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) service that look similar.

```
# For validating login
http://localhost:51055/api/Login/

# For, let's say, something else.
http://localhost:51055/api/Login/
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public LoginData Get(LoginData loginData)
{
  // Do task A
  //return an obj of type LoginData
}

[HttpPost]
public LoginData Get2(LoginData loginData)
{
  // Do task B
  //return an obj of type LoginData
}
```

As you can see, I have two services pretty nearly similar... taking similar request parameters and providing similar response parameters.

How can I differentiate which service to call? Is there a way to force/specify which service to call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Route("NameOfAction")] above your controller method. It maps incoming URL requests to actions in your controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Get1")]
public LoginData Get(LoginData loginData)
{
    // Do task A
    //return an obj of type LoginData
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("Get2")]
public LoginData Get2(LoginData loginData)
{
    // Do task B
    //return an obj of type LoginData
}
```

The API call will be *http://localhost:51055/api/Login/Get1*
and *http://localhost:51055/api/Login/Get2*.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.